# No DNS resolving of ipv6 only server

Tags: dns, ipv6

I have a Server with a ipv6 address and created a DNS AAAA-Record for it via "Strato".
If I try to access the site, it wont resolve the Name to an ipv6 adress.

When I change the nameserver to 1.1.1.1 it worked, but I want it to work also from other devices around the globe. So changing nameserver on every device is a bad idea :D

nslookup with 1.1.1.1 as dns
[image]

Any ideas how I can fix this?

EDIT: I added a ipv4 adress and can resolve it. But it wont show the AAAA -.-

EDIT2: Tried it with dig and +trace option. The last entry is the valid ipv6 adress. But if I try it without the +trace or with nslookup I got no answer.

[image]

Comment: Please do not post images wher images are not required.

Comment: My gut feeling on this is that it's possibly being caused by your ISP blocking it in their DNS relay for some weird reason.  It wouldn't be the first time I've seen an ISP do something strange like that.  Have you checked if the domain name can resolve from somewhere else? (Get a friend to check, or local library, or spin up a virtual machine in the cloud and check there).